# One To Many Mapping creates 3 tables

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, h2

Hi i am using one to many mapping with h2 database and hibernate.. my spring boot application creates tables using the entity classes. what i found there are 3 tables being created. So only in case many to many we have a third table to maintain relationship between two. by in my case even in case of one to many i can see 3 tables are being created. can someone shed light on this one.

```
@ApiModel(description = "Class representing a Order placed by custormer")
@Entity
 @Table(name = "order_taken")
  public class Order {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "order_id")
private int orderId;

@Column(name = "quantity")
private int quantity;


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Item> items;


 @ApiModel(description = "Class representing all coffee varieties in our 
   Restaurant")
  @Entity
     @Table(name="items")
     public class Item {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="item_id")
private int itemId;

@Column(name="item_name")
private String itemName;

@Column(name="price")
private double price;
```

For above entity there are 3 tables items , orders_taken, and orders_taken_item.

Answer (score 4):

If you dont want to create relational table then need to specify `@JoinColum`.

Add this in `Order` table:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
private Set<Item> items;
```